# Sonarqube LDAP settings

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

I'm quite new to `LDAP`.

I want to configure LDAP in sonarqube, something like mentioned [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/LDAP+Integration#LDAPIntegration-ConfigurationExamples).

My admin team has provided below details of our LDAP server:

```
DN=CN=cine_ldap,O=CINEDEL
CN=cine_ldap,O=CINEDEL
cn=cine_ldap
displayname=cine_ldap/CINEDEL
objectclass=dominoPerson
objectclass=inetOrgPerson
objectclass=organizationalPerson
objectclass=person
objectclass=top
mailsystem=100
messagestorage=1
encryptincomingmail=0
roamcleansetting=0
roamcleanper=1
availablefordirsync=1
checkpassword=0
passwordchangeinterval=0
passwordgraceperiod=0
sn=cine_ldap
uid=cine_ldap
roaminguser=0
password=<ourPasswd>
ldapURL=<ourURL>
```

How can I makeout required configurations from above given details?

Please suggest.

*Thank you*

Comment: What about the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/LDAP+Integration)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I read the documents, but I still can't figure out many required properties like baseDN for user and group, etc.